# How can I get_or_create a unique model object when user submit a form?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm creating a private commenting system between users from scratch and I need guidance, when an user submit a form the view should `get_or_create` a unique `Room` where only the connected user and the recipient can comment ot with each other.

I don't understand how I can assemble my code to create this feature, here is the **model** I'm using :

```
class Product(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class Room(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    #unique url for each new room
    uuid_url = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False) 
    name = models.TextField()
    ...
```

When user submit through this form POST this to the concerned function on the views.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'new_room_detail' %}">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ product.id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Contact this user">
</form>
```

**views.py**, Here is where I'm lacking knowledge (see code down there for explanation) :

```
def new_room(request):
    try:
        #get the submited product object
        product = Product.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('product_id')) 
    except Gig.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')

    #if it's the first time that the connected user submit product.id to product.creator
    #then create OR get if it already exist, a Room with a unique url
    #in which only request.user and product.creator can comment.

    return redirect(reverse('commenting_room'))

def commenting_room(request, uuid)
    ...
```

I know there is already a `get_or_create` function but I don't understand how I can limit access only to connected (`request.user`) and `product.creator` users. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why don't you just limit anyone else who chooses to comment. If the person trying to comment is not the post creator or the connected user, do not do anything, else let them comment/communicate. This is just a suggestion to think about!

Comment: @BigMonkey89WithaLeg that'd work too, but the question remains the same, I'd still be stuck in how to create_or_get a Room where only these two users can access.

Comment: @KasimovNuriddin create permission for room like 'chat in the room'. If you know both of the users on room creation, assign this permission to both of them. Check the permission when user make any action with room. That it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is to have a composite unique index on product id and commenting user id - so in the `Room` model you need to set `unique_together('user', 'product')` in the Meta options - if one assumes that your relationship fields have been named `user` and `product` respectively.